# Looking for a film where two lovers are told to wait 10 years for each other to see if they really love one another

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a film I saw a long time ago, and I told myself that maybe someone would remember it. I don't remember all of it, only pieces.

I was younger back then; it was maybe 15 years ago, or a bit more, around 2000.

Here's what I remember :

- Two people, a young girl and a young guy, loving each other, are told in a dream by some form of transparent feminine deity that they would have to wait one year before seeing each other again to see if they really love each other
- After this one year, in another dream, the same deity says that they would have to wait another 10 years to test their mutual love
- I remember the young boy then being trained in a clan. Many people with him are around a deep pool of water. Someone throws something (belonging to his mother? A ring?) in the pool and tells him to go get it in the water. He goes, and doesn't make it. He gets out of the pool and says "I can't do it". Then the man who threw the ring in the water tells him to go again. He goes, gets the ring and emerges a grown man. Everybody cheers.
- I remember the young guy, now a grown man (10 years after the last dream?), giving his helmet (Roman helmet?) to a friend before going to sleep and saying he is going to meet somebody.

And I guess he goes dreaming. But I don't really remember anything apart from these scenes.

That's about all of it. Does it ring a bell?

Comment: Sounds really familiar — my girlfriend told me the same thing nine years ago! Can’t wait to see her in 2017!

Comment: Those are some good details. So you watched in in very early 2000?

Comment: I guess so. I've got really good flashes of memory of those scenes. But, curiously, nothing else. I was born in 1990, and I remember being young watching this. Maybe 8 - 12 years old.

Comment: It's probably Alisea, like in user81976' answer, but to be sure, please, try to remember other details. E.g. was the bad guy Christoper Lee? Important plot points: 1) in Alisea, Christoper Lee serially marries his maids and then "absorbs" them (but not so gross as DW's Abzorbaloff!); 2) he can be killed only with a magic dagger; 3) he can transform into a potion and "infect" the one who drinks it.

Comment: p.s. @xhaltar, in which language did you watch this? in Alisea, the main characters (played by Raz Degan and Veronika Logan) were dubbed also in the original Italian; the source fairy (Valeria Marini) was NOT dubbed despite her remarkable terrible acting (YMMV...). Christoper Lee was ironically-in-hindsight dubbed by the soon-to-be dubber of Gandalf, not Saruman.

Comment: That's the one. I'll be commenting in the anwser. I'm a native French speaker, so I must've seen it in French. I didn't remember about any of the faces of the actors (it was so long ago, in 1996, I was 6 years old)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The film you are looking for is the 1996 Italian TV-movie, *Princess Alisea* (original title *Sorellina e il principe del sogno*, i.e. *Little Sister and the dream prince*) by Lamberto Bava.

Translated from the [German Wikipedia entry](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prinzessin_Alisea&prev=search):

> In the forest the young Alisea lives together with her mother and her 5 brothers.
>
> One day the magician Azaret appears and wants to buy Alisea. When her mother refuses, Azaret Alisea's brothers abducted. The mother dies and Alisea sets out to look for her brothers and save her. In Azaret's castle, she was to work as his servant, and later marry him to give him her youth.
>
> At the same time, the King comes home from the war. He expects to attack his son as a young warrior. However, Demian is more interested in poetry, art and music. For fear of ill-treatment, Demian's mother sends the boy with a showman to protect him from his father.
>
> Alisea and Demian meet on the run and fall in love. However, her romance is short-lived. From now on the lovers meet only in their dreams.

The IMDB entry is slightly different (and a bit less intelligible):

> Alisea and her brothers have been captured by Azaret an evil wizard. Alisea escapes the castle and meets the young prince Demian who she falls in love with. The spirit of the source promises that they will always be together if they are to drink from its source. Alisea is again caught by the magician and Demian has to return to his father cone, which aims to turn him into a warrior. Seven years later, Demian becomes a warrior, but has not forgotten Alisea, who he sees in his dreams .Azaret tries to prevente Demian and Alisea from begin together.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Can you provide any background for the movie you name to describe how it matches what OP is looking for?

Comment: So does the movie have some stuff relating to being apart for 10 years?  Because like...

Comment: I remember that period, Italian (not ItaliaM, please!) directors had some sort of fantasy craze. In that two-parter TV-movie, the evil wizard was a great pre-LOTR Christoper Lee! I don't remember parts with a ring in a pool, unfortunately, but that does not mean there weren't; I remember slightly better some scenes the second half, with Azaret/Lee "possessing" Demian and making him a bloodthirst warrior. Demian somehow snaps out of it (power of love?), swears he'll study war no more, and stupdly throws away the magic dagger, the only weapon that can kill Azaret (facepalm!).

Comment: Indeed it is. I had little glimpse of memories back to me seeing your video. I found every points I mentionned in my question, that's a good find